# TypeError: get_tier_by_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) in Pycharm

Tags: python

During the execution of this code  on pycharm I got the following error:

```
TypeError: get_tier_by_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Here is the code

```
import os
import tgt
from pydub import AudioSegment

tg = tgt.read_textgrid("arabic1_0.TextGrid")
ipu_tier = tg.get_tier_by_name(0,60)
xmin = ipu_tier[1]._start_time
xmax = ipu_tier[1]._end_time
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("arabic1.wav")
goal_split_wav = audio[xmin * 1000:xmax * 1000]
goal_split_wav.export("output_path")  # the path of the splited wav
```

Comment: Please share the `get_tier_by_name` method definition.

Comment: @vahdet apparently https://github.com/hbuschme/TextGridTools/blob/master/tgt/core.py#L96

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 2 arguments, it requires 1:

in     tgt/core.py:

```
     def get_tier_by_name(self, name):
        '''Get the first tier with the specified name.'''
        for tier in self._tiers:
            if tier.name == name:
                return tier
        raise ValueError('Textgrid ' + self.filename +
                ' does not have a tier called "' + name + '".')
```

You are passing 2 numbers, you should pass it a str with the name of the tier

You can check the tier names with get_tier_names

```
names =  tg.get_tier_names()
```

Comment: No, they are passing 3 arguments not 2 as the traceback says, the first being `tg` i.e. the instance itself

Comment: yes, sorry typo, it is implicit in the answer I mean you are passing 2 it requires 1 ( as an explanation of you are passing 3 requires 2, one being self which you don't have to pass)